# TIme the period between two actions on separate pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have 2 pages. On page-a.php a user clicks a button, which creates page-2.php and after completing some tasks on that second page the user click "Submit" button, at which point I would like to turn off the timer. I would like to record that time using Google Analytics which I think I can do with something like that:

```
// Feature detects Navigation Timing API support.
if (window.performance) {
    // Gets the number of milliseconds since page load
    // (and rounds the result since the value must be an integer).
    var timeSincePageLoad = Math.round(performance.now());

    // Sends the timing event to Google Analytics.
    gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {
    'name': 'load',
    'value': timeSincePageLoad,
    'event_category': 'JS Dependencies'
  });
}
```

The question is how do I start that timer and keep it across pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Across pages you can use cookie storage. I think in your case you should save in cookie timestamp of first page view and timestamp of button "Submit" click on second page. Cookie expiration time - 30 min, for example. Then calculate time difference and send event with custom metric to GA triggered by click "Submit" just after calculating. In report you'll have time from view page one to click "Submit" within one session, if I understood correctly what do you need.